# svg animation not animating smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Here I give code of html which not work properly, how can I get it to move smoothly?

I am happy to use jQuery if necessary.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                        width="1362px" height="219px" viewBox="0 0 1362 219" enable-background="new 0 0 1362 219" xml:space="preserve" class="header-svg-nav">
                    <g id="Shape_1">
                        <g>
                            <path fill="#454545" d="M1361.7-0.1L124.1,0.1L4,161.7c0,0-27.6,61.2,61,57.2s1297-110.5,1297-110.5L1361.7-0.1 z" class="header-svg-nav">
                            <animate attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" repeatCount="indefinite"
                            values="M1361.7-0.1L124.1,0.1L4,161.7c0,0-27.6,61.2,61,57.2s1297-110.5,1297-110.5L1361.7-0.1 z; 
                            M1361.7-0.1 L124.1,0.1 L4,161.7 c0,0-9.6,21.3,0.7,37.9 c9.5,15.4,31.4,19.7,60.3,19.3
    c70.7-1,109.2-28.3,161-41.9 c87.3-22.9,103,21.9,238,14c64.4-3.8,55.7-13.6,143-25 c129.3-16.8,154.8,4,273-7 c118.6-11,125.3-35,230-45 c107.5-10.2,196.2,5.9,252,20  C1361.9,89.3,1361.8,44.6,1361.7-0.1z;" begin="0s" dur="5s"/>
                            </path>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An animation with easing between two path definitions can only work if they match structurally.

- They must have the same number of control points and all path commands must be identical.
- You cannot exchange absolute (`C`) commands for relative (`c`), or shorthand curve commands (`S`) for full (`C`).
- Optional command letters (for repetitions of the same command) can be used or left out.
- Whitespace can have different length or be exchanged for commas.

The reason for that is actually not that hard to understand: To compute an interim state, the renderer needs to formulate a path definition by choosing an appropriate value *between* the "from" and "to", for every control point. There can be no computed interim if the letters or the number of points differ.

Currently you go from

```
M1361.7-0.1L124.1,0.1L4,161.7c0,0-27.6,61.2,61,57.2s1297-110.5,1297-110.5L1361.7-0.1 z
```

to a much longer command

```
M1361.7-0.1 L124.1,0.1 L4,161.7 c0,0-9.6,21.3,0.7,37.9 c9.5,15.4,31.4,19.7,60.3,19.3 c70.7-1,109.2-28.3,161-41.9 c87.3-22.9,103,21.9,238,14c64.4-3.8,55.7-13.6,143-25 c129.3-16.8,154.8,4,273-7 c118.6-11,125.3-35,230-45 c107.5-10.2,196.2,5.9,252,20  C1361.9,89.3,1361.8,44.6,1361.7-0.1z
```

That is much too different.

And there is a fair amount of work involved to get them to match. I don't know if Illustrator will be helpfull in that regard. It changes commands for what it deems optimal and if that happens in one command variant and not the other, easing will still not work. The only thing you can rely on is writing down the path commands in a text editor one below the other and comparing number for number, letter for letter.

The version below was worked out with Inkscape, some experience, and a lot of trial and error.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                        width="1362px" height="219px" viewBox="0 0 1362 219" enable-background="new 0 0 1362 219" xml:space="preserve" class="header-svg-nav">
                    <g id="Shape_1">
                        <g>
                            <path fill="#454545" d="M1361.7-0.1L124.1,0.1L4,161.7c0,0-27.6,61.2,61,57.2s1297-110.5,1297-110.5L1361.7-0.1 z" class="header-svg-nav">
                            <animate attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" repeatCount="indefinite"
                            values="M 1361.7,-0.1 124.1,0.1 4,161.7 C 4,161.7 -23.6,222.9 65,218.9 82,218.1 140.1,213.6 222.9,206.8 289.6,201.3 372.4,194.3 462.7,186.6 509.1,182.6 557.4,178.5 606.6,174.3 697.4,166.4 790.9,158.3 879.9,150.6 962.2,143.4 1040.7,136.6 1109.4,130.6 1193.6,123.2 1277.8,115.8 1362,108.4 Z; 
                                    M 1361.7,-0.1 124.1,0.1 4,161.7 C 4,161.7 -23.6,222.9 65,218.9 135.7,217.9 174.2,190.6 226,177 313.3,154.1 329,198.9 464,191 528.4,187.2 519.7,177.4 607,166 736.3,149.2 761.8,170 880,159 998.6,148 1005.3,124 1110,114 1217.5,103.8 1306.2,119.9 1362,134 Z;" begin="0s" dur="5s"/>
                            </path>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
```

Comment: great answer! :-)

Comment: there is one more mistake, when go out its faster how is it.

Comment: can you fix it which is still problem with svg please